# How to swap n bits from 2 numbers?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, swap

So currently (I don't know if the width is relevant) I have 2 128bit integers that I want to swap `shift` bits as `shift` is a part of a structure:

```
unsigned char shift : 7;
```

So I get the relevant bits like this:

```
__uint128_t rawdata = ((*pfirst << shift) >> shift), rawdatasecond = ((*psecond << shift) >> shift);
```

And then I swap them like this:

```
*pfirst = *pfirst >> 127 - shift << 127 - shift | rawdatasecond;

*psecond = *psecond >> 127 - shift << 127 - shift | rawdata;
```

But I feel like I'm missing something - or am I (not sure how to test either)?

Note:

```
__uint128_t *pfirst, *psecond; //pointer to some integers
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after.  A real-world example of your stated operation would be very useful, or perhaps an example containing an input and the expected output.  In any case, when I encounter a problem like this, my first port of call is always https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just want to successfully swap the first n bits from the number (while leaving the rest bits the same). I'm not sure how to test though.

Comment: You test it by writing it as a function, and then passing candidate values to the function to see if you get the expected outputs.

Comment: Just like you would test any other function.  This particular function is unremarkable in that regard.

Comment: `*pfirst = *pfirst >> 127 - shift << 127 - shift | rawdatasecond;` **<<--** start by adding some `()`

Comment: @wildplasser Ok but assuming I correct that will it work ? And how could we know?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand the task, you would like to swap bits 0, ..., n-1 for two integers. This can be done as follows:

```
static inline void swapbits(__uint128_t *a, __uint128_t *b, unsigned n)
{
    if(n <= 8 * sizeof(*a))
    {
        __uint128_t mask = (n < 8 *sizeof(*a)) ? (((__uint128_t)1) << n) - 1 : ~(__uint128_t)0;
        __uint128_t bits_a = *a & mask;  // Get the bits from a
        __uint128_t bits_b = *b & mask;  // Get the bits from b
        *a = (*a & ~mask) | bits_b;    // Set bits in a
        *b = (*b & ~mask) | bits_a;    // Set bits in b
    }
}
```

Testing is a matter of calling the function with different combinations of values for `a`, `b` and `n` and checking that the result is as expected.

Clearly it is not feasible to test all combinations so a number of representative cases must be defined. It is not an exact science, but think about middle and corner cases: n=0, n=1, n=64, n=127, n=128 and a and b having different bit patterns around the left-most and right-most positions as well as around the n'th position.

Comment: OK. my mistake, the code works for `128`.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void SwapHighNBits(__uint128_t *a, __uint128_t *b, size_t n)
{
    //  Calculate number of uninvolved bits.
    size_t NU = 128 - n;

    //  Calculate bitwise difference and remove uninvolved bits.
    __uint128_t d = (*a ^ *b) >> NU << NU;

    //  Apply difference.
    *a ^= d;
    *b ^= d;
}
```

A good test suite would include all combinations of bits in the critical positions: The high bit, the lowest bit swapped, the highest bit not swapped, and the lowest bit. That is four bits in each of two operands, so eight bits total, 256 combinations for a specific value of `n`. Then test values of `n` from 2 to 126. Other bits can be filled randomly.

For `n` = 1, the high bit and the lowest bit swapped are identical, so make separate test code for that, or write the common test code carefully to cover that. Similarly, for `n` = 127, the highest bit not swapped and the lowest bit are identical, and, for `n` = 128, there are no bits not swapped.

If defined behavior is defined for `n` ≤ 0 or `n` > 128, add test cases for those. Note that the code above does not support `n` = 0, as `NU` will be 128, and the shifts are not defined by the C standard. Of course, for `n` = 0, one can simply return without making any changes.

Comment: You could simply wrap the code in a test `if (n) {}` to fix the corner case for `n = 0`.